# Search in a string using regex [python]

Tags: python, regex

I'm searching this text:

```
22min 7s 11.2km
```

The pattern is always:
{1,2} numbers + 'min' + space + {1,2} numbers + 's' + space + {1,2,3} numbers + . + {1,2} numbers + 'km'

*spaces can ou cannot exist - and sometimes . is coming as ,

I'm using re.search to find but I'm having problems.

```
item = re.search('\s(\d{1,2}\w{min}\d{1,2}\w{s}\s{1,2,3}\w{km})', img1).group(1)
```

Comment: sorry buddy...

item = re.search('\s(\d{1,2}\w{min}\d{1,2}\w{s}\s{1,2,3}\w{km})', img1).group(1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
m = re.search(r'\d{1,2}min\s+\d{1,2}s\s+\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?km', img1)
if m:
    item = m.group()
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nxgQ83/1). *Details*:

- `\d{1,2}` - one or two digits
- `min` - a word `min`
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `\d{1,2}s` - one or two digits and `s`
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?` - one or more digits, and then `.` or `,` and one or more digits (optionally)
- `km` - a `km` string.